# Android - Opening a webpage and back to Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-intent

Let's say I am on an Activity, user clicks a button, and I navigate to a web page.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("SOME_URL"));
startActivity(i);
```

it takes me to the web page, and then when I click back to goes to my activity, but it starts it all over again. 
So is it possible to do this in a way so that after clicking the back button, it takes me to my activity, but instead of `onCreate` it call `onRestart`.
The goal is not going through `onCreate` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the normal life cycle of an Activity... you could save the state of the activity and restore it to get the "same" as before.

The main question should be: Why do you not want to go through onCreate? If it goes through it because it was destroyed before and need to be recreated. So not going through it will cause a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an intent in your activity (setIntent) before calling the web browser, then in your onCreate method, check for if this intent called you back (check the intent name or an extra) and if so, skip the rest of onCreate.

Before calling web browser :

```
Intent intentForThis = new Intent( "AfterWebBroswer" );
this.setIntent( intentForThis );

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("SOME_URL"));
startActivity(i);
```

And then in your onCreateMethod

```
public void onCreate( Bundle b ) {
    if( !getIntent().getAction().equals("AfterWebBrowser") ) {
       //rest of onCreate
    }//if
}//met
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: skipping the onCreate this way means, that everything that would be done, like setting the layout, fill it with data, set listeners will be completely ignored. It probably will just create a blank screen or a screen without the possibility to interact or even display the correct content. Thats why I asked why he want to skip it...

Comment: Sure it would, but still here is  a way to do what @aryaxt wanted

Comment: Sorry if this may sound rude, its not meant to be offensive but: just providing a solution without educating about the possible problems and that it isn't the way it should be done is ok?

Comment: Good point, but I assumed someone with twice my reputation here knows what he wants and doesn't need a trivial course on app lifecycles. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: Reputation is not always a sign of knowledge :) I got my points basically from answers for android, you shouldn't trust my c knowledge :D